# Protect Datasheet with regard to cell fomat/border

Tags: excel, vba

Hello Excle'rs and Vba'ers,

I'd like to know if it's possible to set certain limitations protecting the excel datasheet with an password. My protected excel sheet has a certain "unprotected" range of cells, where the user can fill in data.

Unfortunately I want to limitate the user to only fill in data, BUT NOT change the background color or border size of those cells. Is this possible? Maybe with some VBA code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then there is a way.

Step 1) Select the cells you want the user to be able to fill data into and then format those cells such that they have an UNCHECKED "Locked" property.

[image]

Step 2) Right click the worksheet's tab and select "Protect Sheet..."

[image]

Step 3) Make sure "Select unlocked cells" is checked and "Format cells" is UNCHECKED. Here's how that might look:

[image]

Now your worksheet should be locked, yet users can still enter data into the cells you "unlocked" in step 1. But they cannot change the fill or border situation of any cells in the worksheet, because they cannot format any cells in the worksheet.